# How to render dynamic number of cards on the new page depending on the data received from a query in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, pug, backend

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    title Property List
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/prop-list-style.css')
  body
    // partial:index.partial.html  https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=10
    .main
      h1(data-text='Property List') Property List
      ul.cards
        li.cards_item
          .card
            .card_image
              img(src='https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=10')
            .card_content
              h2.card_title Antila Housing
              p.card_text 3 BHK
              p.card_text Price: 70 Lakhs
              a(href='description.html')
                button.btn.card_btn Find Out More
        li.cards_item
          .card
            .card_image
              img(src='https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=5')
            .card_content
              h2.card_title Akash Housing
              p.card_text 2 BHK
              p.card_text Price: 55 Lakhs
              a(href='description.html')
                button.btn.card_btn Find out more
        li.cards_item
          .card
            .card_image
              img(src='https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=11')
            .card_content
              h2.card_title Sky Valley Housing
              p.card_text 1 BHK
              p.card_text Price: 40 Lakhs
              a(href='description.html')
                button.btn.card_btn Find out more
        li.cards_item
          .card
            .card_image
              img(src='https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=14')
            .card_content
              h2.card_title Ariana Apartment
              p.card_text 2 BHK
              p.card_text Price: 50 Lakhs
              button.btn.card_btn Find Out More
        li.cards_item
          .card
            .card_image
              img(src='https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=17')
            .card_content
              h2.card_title Apartment 51
              p.card_text 1 BHK
              p.card_text Price: 43 Lakhs
              button.btn.card_btn Find Out More
        li.cards_item
          .card
            .card_image
              img(src='https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=2')
            .card_content
              h2.card_title Apartment Aloha
              p.card_text 1 BHK
              p.card_text Price: 54 Lakhs
              button.btn.card_btn Find Out More
    // partial
```

I have this jade template file which I want to render.

```
   console.log(rowi[0]);
                    //Render the list on next page
                    // rowi is the array of object containing the result of a query.
                    res.render('propList');
```

The render function will be called using res.render('proplist'), which is rendering the jade file on the browser.

How can I make the number of cards dynamic on the rendered page depending on the number of objects I received from query result in another route js file?

Please mention the specific changes I have to make.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Pug documentation on iteration and loops](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)?

Comment: Yes I did, and Now I am make the number of cards dynamic.I had to just iterate over the array of objects using loop.